# NAS disappearing

Tags: wireless-networking, nas, ubiquiti

Dear fellow superusers please help save my sanity.
This is a network question and I have no idea if this is the right forum.

I wanted to get into Ubiquiti as easy as possible so I bought 2 unifi 6 lite AP's and a lite switch. I have kept my ISP router/modem and turned off Wifi.

I have pulled a lot of cables to get as many devices on ethernet as possible including my NAS from Synology. Wifi works, cables work. For some reason I can't access my NAS from wifi and it's driving me nuts.

I have a lot of parts where things can go wrong, but I can't find anything not working. My NAS is wired through: Router -> Lite switch -> wall plug -> TP-link switch -> NAS.
I find it super quick with ethernet. On wifi it just hangs.

I have no idea what setting to test or what to try now. Please advice.

Comment: Did you set up the Ubiquiti Controller?  And did you set up the Ubqquiti AP with a Static IP (so the NAS always knows where to look)?

Comment: Synology has an app you can download from their website or through the chrome web store called Find my Synology. It will scan your network and find any synology, then setup a link so you can access it. I expect that this is a matter of having to change the IPAddress of the nas and place it inside the network range.

Comment: I set up the Ubiquiti Controller on my computer but I have not set the AP's with Static IP, I'll try that.

Comment: The NAS has a static IP which should be within network range but I will try the app.

Comment: But the NAS is wired so should it need to know about the AP's?

Comment: As long as it is discoverable on the network somehow it should work. Your phone can be connected to the AP, and the NAS can be wired.

Answer (score 0):

OM**. Okay I think I found the reason. I had tried to turn off and  redirect DHCP on UniFi, so  it wouldn't handle any of that but let the router do. Apparently, I had done something wrong because when I manually set the address of the router in DHCP to 192.168.0.1 instead of 192.168.1.1 which UniFi automatically have, it started showing up.

Basically, I had involuntarily created a VLAN.

I guess I don't properly understand how their DHCP relay function works or what happens when I turn it off.